# Mixing Freemarker and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, freemarker

I have a freemarker template and jQuery on the page.
The issue is related to both languages using `$` for evaluation

Freemarker template

```
<#assign mode = app.mode>
<#assign namespace = app.namespace>
<#if mode =="view">
 <script>
  //   execute some script..
  <script>
<#elseif mode == "edit">
 <script>
   ${namespace}init();
   function ${namespace}init(){
       //init code..
   }
 <script>
</#if>
```

In the script tag i want to namespace the functions but i get `namespace is not defined.` I think its jquery trying to evaluate ${namespace} but i want freemarker to evaluate it so that function can be namespaced

Any idea how this could be achieved?

Comment: Why, does `${namespace}` mean anything for jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

As FreeMarker is a server side template language the expression ${namespace} should be long gone before JavaScript/jQuery kicks in...in other words ${namespace} would have been replaced with whatever the namespace variable (FreeMarker) contains before jQuery can see it...what do you see if you view the page source that is rendered?

What happens if you try to put the call to namespace_init() AFTER the function declaration (shouldn't be the problem as you don't assign the function to a variable, but who knows...)

Plus, you could just do the following and save one <#assign />:

```
function ${app.namespace}_init() {
    // your init code
}

${app.namespace}_init();
```